# Asp.NET MVC Razor DropDownList and document with table part

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, visual-studio-2013, html.dropdownlistfor

I need to make a drop-down list box, which selects data from the related table.

I've used an example from MSDN, but it doesn't work.

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    TypeItemsDropDownList();
    return View(new Item());
}

//
// POST: /Item/Create

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "idItem,nameItem,priceItem,quantity,inStock,descrItem,idTypeItem")]Item item)
{
    try
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            iac.StoreNewItem(item);
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
    }
    catch (System.Data.DataException)
    {
        //Log the error (add a variable name after DataException) 
        ModelState.AddModelError("", "Unable to save changes. Try again, and if the problem persists, see your system administrator.");
    }
    TypeItemsDropDownList(item.idTypeItem);
    return View(item); 
}

private void TypeItemsDropDownList(object selectedTypeItem = null)
{
    cabproddbEntities db = new cabproddbEntities();
    var typeQuery = from d in db.TypeItem
                    orderby d.nameTypeItem
                    select d;
    ViewBag.idTypeItem = new SelectList(typeQuery, "idTypeItem", "nameTypeItem", selectedTypeItem);
}
```

The error occurs here:

```
<div class="editor-label">
    <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="idTypeItem">Тип продукции</label>
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.DropDownList("idTypeItem", String.Empty)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.idTypeItem)
</div>
```

on this line: `@Html.DropDownList("idTypeItem", String.Empty)`

The table `TypeItem` has the data.

The thrown exception is: `System.Data.EntityCommandExecutionException` with the following details:

> The text, ntext, and image data types cannot be compared or sorted, except when using IS NULL or LIKE operator.

Comment: need your complete Error message?

Comment: Sorry, forgot about the text of the error:

Comment: @KseniyaTsk Fixed your other question too. Please take some time to at least try to make your questions more readable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is you are not linking your `SelectList` to the drop down. Use the `DropDownListFor()` helper and reference your select list in it. As shown below.

Your naming conventions are a little off also and this might be leading you into confusion.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => Model.selectedItem, ViewBag.idTypeItem)
```